# I can not log in using this code. What is the error?

Tags: java, android, authentication

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log);

    Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETNAME);
    Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETpassword);
    Info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVinfo);
    Login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BTlogin);

    Info.setText("No of attempts remaining: 5");

    Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            validate(Name.getText().toString(), Password.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}
private void validate(String UserName, String UserPassword){

    if((UserName == "Starlite") && (UserPassword == "abc123")){
        Intent intent = new Intent(LOGActivity.this, InterfaceActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }else{
        counter--;
        Info.setText("No of attempts remaining: " + String.valueOf(counter));

        if(counter == 0){
            Login.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

}
```

}

This is my code and I created it to log to a profile. But I can not login with it. What is the error of it? The following are the top code. I done with it with tutorials. But it not working.It was verified in 5 times. But can not log to it.

Comment: (UserName == "Starlite") google equals. trust me, you'll love it.

Comment: [Really](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=equals&oq=equals&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j0l2.871j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)? Equals, the film?